# Why does mingw-w64 support strcpy_s() while tdm-gcc fails compiling that call?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm trying to compile an open source library from bitbucket for various platforms. Compiling for Windows works only using the mingw-w64/32 4.8 compiler. Other compilers like tdm-gcc 5.1 fail at those lines calling "strcpy_s", stating they are not defined in this scope. On Linux, compiling works without a problem using the standard gcc on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm aware of the workaround to replace the (c++ 11) strcpy_s with std::strcpy.

I don't understand why this is happening because the tdm-gcc is even more up to date than the mingw-w64 version.

Comment: There's no `strcpy_s` in C++.

Comment: I read somewhere at wikipedia that it is definied withing the c++ 11 standard. [OtherSourceIJustGoogledUp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)

Comment: @SchroedingersHat It is part of C11 but is not part of the current C++.  see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) for the C++ `strcpy`.  `strcpy_s` may get included into C++ in a future version.

Comment: @SchroedingersHat: No, that's a different language. (And in C11 the `_s` functions are optional. They were mandatory in C99.)

Comment: But C++11 is supported since GCC 4.8 (with 4.8.1 supporting all major features). And, like I said, no problems with that code compiling on Linux or using mingw-w64.

Comment: @KerrekSB Why is it a problem to use C++11 with a C++11 supporting compiler at all?

Comment: @SchroedingersHat But there is no `strcpy_s` in `C++11`. There is one in `C11` which is different language. And even there it is optional, which means that _any_ compiler might just decide to not have it.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thank you, I didn't know C also had an 11 update and thought it's an abbreviation for C++11. 

So even though mingw-w64 and tdm-gcc both use the gcc, they may include the optinal _s functions fully on their behalf? 

And what is happening on Linux and mingw-w64 that these compilers produce working builds?

Comment: @SchroedingersHat GCC brings some C features in C++ as compiler extensions. You can (and honestly, should) force strict standard compliance which will turn off those.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thank you, that really helped me.

Comment: Is anyone going to write an answer? Or will all the useful information remain in the comments section?