# strcpy_s not working with gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, strcpy, tr24731

I have a C++11 project, and I added some `strcpy_s` method calls.
This works on windows, but when compiling on gcc, there is an error
stating that `strcpy_s` symbol is not found.

I did add the line

`#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1`

to the code, to no avail.

Comment: Did you look up the function to find out what it is, and where it is supported? Looks like a C11 feature to me based on a quick Google search, and C++11/C++14 are based on C99. Kinda similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37569204/560648

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any free implementations of strcpy\_s and/or TR24731-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067728/are-there-any-free-implementations-of-strcpy-s-and-or-tr24731-1)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

GCC (or rather, glibc) does not support `strcpy_s()` and friends.  For some ideas on where you can find a library which does support them, see here: [Are there any free implementations of strcpy_s and/or TR24731-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067728/are-there-any-free-implementations-of-strcpy-s-and-or-tr24731-1)

Comment: Thanks, John. I just ended up implementing it myself.

Answer (score 10):

`strcpy_s` and friends are not a part of C++ just yet. It seems that [C++17](http://eel.is/c++draft/headers#tab:c.annex.k.names) will have them, but as of now providing them is up to the implementations. It seems glibc doesn't.

In fact, according to the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy), `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` will only work if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined. On my Arch Linux it isn't.

```
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
constexpr bool can_have_strcpy_s = true;
#else
constexpr bool can_have_strcpy_s = false;
#endif
```

You can use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy). With some care, it can be safe.

Comment: Re: "Why don't you use strncpy, though?" -- um, because it doesn't work? Yes, you can make it work, but it wasn't designed to be a "safe" replacement for `strcpy`, and it isn't.